# SSL Failure on GET request with Groovy HttpBuilder

Tags: ssl, groovy, https

I can not make a GET request on the following link using Groovy's HttpBuilder: https://system.planassist.mpu.mp.br/production/login.aspx

I already tested the method below:

```
ignoreSSLIssues()
```

But the exception always returns:

```
Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Code example:

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.Method

def http = new HTTPBuilder("https://sistema.planassiste.mpu.mp.br/producao/login.aspx")
http.ignoreSSLIssues()
http.request(Method.GET) { req ->

}
```

Result:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:220)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:515)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:434)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:366)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$request.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
```

WORKS:

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.Method
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients

def http = new HTTPBuilder("https://sistema.planassiste.mpu.mp.br/producao/login.aspx")
http.client = HttpClients.createSystem()
http.request(Method.GET) { req ->

}
```

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: Add in question!